# AngularJs Yeoman creating a different directory structure

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am going to start with a new client side AngularJS project for the first time next week. If I use yeoman to create the project, the directory layout is such that all controllers in one folder, all services in one folder and so on. 
Is there any way to use Yeoman to create a project such that folders are created based on functionality, for example, login, users, property; and each one consists of scripts(js), templates (html) corresponding to them. 
If this is not possible with the current Yeoman implementation, can I use yeoman to create angular project and then change the default directory layout keeping app.js and index.html in their old positions. If this is done, will grunt serve work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters), specifically rows 132-137 of the Starters sheet and the File Structures sheet.

There are many alternatives to generator-angular and many of them organize files as you describe.